# Substituting for loop to run in parallel in R

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have this for loop:

```
library(EnvStats)
mvfyfueu <- matrix(, nrow = 0, ncol = 3)
for (i in 1:2000 ) {

  # fy (S355, yield strength N/mm2)
  meanmean = 419.38 #(*)
  sdmean = 10 #(**)
  meanmeanlv = 400 #(**)
  meanmeanuv = 440 #(**)
  meanfy <- dist(meanmean,sdmean,meanmeanlv,meanmeanuv,"norm")

  meansd = 20.25 #(*)
  sdsd = 5 #(**)
  meansdlv = 15 #(**)
  meansduv = 25 #(**)
  sdfy <- dist(meansd,sdsd,meansdlv,meansduv,"norm")

  fylv = 355 #(*)
  fyuv = 500 #(**)  
  lsupfy <- 1 - plnormTruncAlt(fyuv, mean = meanfy[1], cv = sdfy[1]/meanfy[1]) - 1e-10
  linffy <- plnormTruncAlt(fylv, mean = meanfy[1], cv = sdfy[1]/meanfy[1]) - 1e-10

  # fu (S355, tensile strength N/mm2)
  meanmean = 533.44 #(*)
  sdmean = 10 #(**)
  meanmeanlv = 500 #(**)
  meanmeanuv = 550 #(**)
  meanfu <- dist(meanmean,sdmean,meanmeanlv,meanmeanuv,"norm")

  meansd = 16.53 #(*)
  sdsd = 5 #(**)
  meansdlv = 10 #(**)
  meansduv = 25 #(**)
  sdfu <- dist(meansd,sdsd,meansdlv,meansduv,"norm")

  fulv = 470 #(*)
  fuuv = 630 #(*)  
  lsupfu <- 1 - plnormTruncAlt(fuuv, mean = meanfu[1], cv = sdfu[1]/meanfu[1]) - 1e-10
  linffu <- plnormTruncAlt(fulv, mean = meanfu[1], cv = sdfu[1]/meanfu[1]) - 1e-10

  # eu (S355, strain at maximum strength mm/mm)
  meanmean = 0.2645 #(*)
  sdmean = 10 #(**)
  meanmeanlv = 0.2 #(**)
  meanmeanuv = 0.3 #(**)
  meaneu <- dist(meanmean,sdmean,meanmeanlv,meanmeanuv,"norm")

  meansd = 0.0613 #(*)
  sdsd = 0.02 #(**)
  meansdlv = 0.02 #(**)
  meansduv = 0.1 #(**)
  sdeu <- dist(meansd,sdsd,meansdlv,meansduv,"norm")

  eulv = 0.1 #(*)
  euuv = 0.3 #(*)  
  lsupeu <- 1 - plnormTruncAlt(euuv, mean = meaneu[1], cv = sdeu[1]/meaneu[1]) - 1e-10
  linfeu <- plnormTruncAlt(eulv, mean = meaneu[1], cv = sdeu[1]/meaneu[1]) - 1e-10

  #Generate samples
  mat.fyfueu <- simulateMvMatrix(2000,
                              distributions = c(fy = "lnormAlt",fu = "lnormAlt",eu = "lnormAlt"),
                              param.list = list(fy = list(mean=meanfy[1], cv=sdfy[1]/meanfy[1]),
                                                fu = list(mean=meanfu[1], cv=sdfu[1]/meanfu[1]),
                                                eu = list(mean=meaneu[1], cv=sdeu[1]/meaneu[1])),
                              left.tail.cutoff = c(fy = ifelse(linffy <= 1e-5, 0, linffy),
                                                      fu = ifelse(linffu <= 1e-5, 0, linffu),
                                                      eu = ifelse(linfeu <= 1e-5, 0, linfeu)),
                              right.tail.cutoff = c(fy = ifelse(lsupfy <= 0, .Machine$double.eps, lsupfy),
                                                       fu = ifelse(lsupfu <= 0, .Machine$double.eps, lsupfu),
                                                       eu = ifelse(lsupeu <= 0, .Machine$double.eps, lsupeu)),
                              cor.mat = matrix(c(1, .75, -0.45, .75, 1, -0.6, -0.45, -0.6, 1), 3, 3),
                              sample.method = "LHS", max.iter = 100) #, seed = i

  mvfyfueu <- rbind2(mvfyfueu, mat.fyfueu)
}
```

*dist* function:

```
dist <- function(meanv, sdv, lv, uv, dist) {
  library(EnvStats)
  lsup <- 1 - pnorm(uv, mean = meanv, sd = sdv)
  linf <- pnorm(lv, mean = meanv, sd = sdv)
  value <- simulateVector(2, distribution = dist,
                       param.list = list(mean = meanv, sd = sdv), #seed = i,
                       sort = FALSE, left.tail.cutoff = ifelse(linf == 0, .Machine$double.eps, linf),
                       right.tail.cutoff = ifelse(lsup == 0, .Machine$double.eps, lsup), sample.method = "LHS")
  return(value)
}
```

Now I want to run it in parallel so I change it to:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
#setup parallel backend to use 7 processors
cl<-makeCluster(7)
registerDoParallel(cl)
library(EnvStats)
mvfyfueu <- matrix(, nrow = 0, ncol = 3)
iters <- 100
foreach(icount(iters)) %dopar% {

  # fy (S355, yield strength N/mm2)
  meanmean = 419.38 #(*)
  sdmean = 10 #(**)
  meanmeanlv = 400 #(**)
  meanmeanuv = 440 #(**)
  meanfy <- dist(meanmean,sdmean,meanmeanlv,meanmeanuv,"norm")

  meansd = 20.25 #(*)
  sdsd = 5 #(**)
  meansdlv = 15 #(**)
  meansduv = 25 #(**)
  sdfy <- dist(meansd,sdsd,meansdlv,meansduv,"norm")

  fylv = 355 #(*)
  fyuv = 500 #(**)  
  lsupfy <- 1 - plnormTruncAlt(fyuv, mean = meanfy[1], cv = sdfy[1]/meanfy[1]) - 1e-10
  linffy <- plnormTruncAlt(fylv, mean = meanfy[1], cv = sdfy[1]/meanfy[1]) - 1e-10

  # fu (S355, tensile strength N/mm2)
  meanmean = 533.44 #(*)
  sdmean = 10 #(**)
  meanmeanlv = 500 #(**)
  meanmeanuv = 550 #(**)
  meanfu <- dist(meanmean,sdmean,meanmeanlv,meanmeanuv,"norm")

  meansd = 16.53 #(*)
  sdsd = 5 #(**)
  meansdlv = 10 #(**)
  meansduv = 25 #(**)
  sdfu <- dist(meansd,sdsd,meansdlv,meansduv,"norm")

  fulv = 470 #(*)
  fuuv = 630 #(*)  
  lsupfu <- 1 - plnormTruncAlt(fuuv, mean = meanfu[1], cv = sdfu[1]/meanfu[1]) - 1e-10
  linffu <- plnormTruncAlt(fulv, mean = meanfu[1], cv = sdfu[1]/meanfu[1]) - 1e-10

  # eu (S355, strain at maximum strength mm/mm)
  meanmean = 0.2645 #(*)
  sdmean = 10 #(**)
  meanmeanlv = 0.2 #(**)
  meanmeanuv = 0.3 #(**)
  meaneu <- dist(meanmean,sdmean,meanmeanlv,meanmeanuv,"norm")

  meansd = 0.0613 #(*)
  sdsd = 0.02 #(**)
  meansdlv = 0.02 #(**)
  meansduv = 0.1 #(**)
  sdeu <- dist(meansd,sdsd,meansdlv,meansduv,"norm")

  eulv = 0.1 #(*)
  euuv = 0.3 #(*)  
  lsupeu <- 1 - plnormTruncAlt(euuv, mean = meaneu[1], cv = sdeu[1]/meaneu[1]) - 1e-10
  linfeu <- plnormTruncAlt(eulv, mean = meaneu[1], cv = sdeu[1]/meaneu[1]) - 1e-10

  #Generate samples
  mat.fyfueu <- simulateMvMatrix(2000,
                                 distributions = c(fy = "lnormAlt",fu = "lnormAlt",eu = "lnormAlt"),
                                 param.list = list(fy = list(mean=meanfy[1], cv=sdfy[1]/meanfy[1]),
                                                   fu = list(mean=meanfu[1], cv=sdfu[1]/meanfu[1]),
                                                   eu = list(mean=meaneu[1], cv=sdeu[1]/meaneu[1])),
                                 left.tail.cutoff = c(fy = ifelse(linffy <= 1e-5, 0, linffy),
                                                      fu = ifelse(linffu <= 1e-5, 0, linffu),
                                                      eu = ifelse(linfeu <= 1e-5, 0, linfeu)),
                                 right.tail.cutoff = c(fy = ifelse(lsupfy <= 0, .Machine$double.eps, lsupfy),
                                                       fu = ifelse(lsupfu <= 0, .Machine$double.eps, lsupfu),
                                                       eu = ifelse(lsupeu <= 0, .Machine$double.eps, lsupeu)),
                                 cor.mat = matrix(c(1, .75, -0.45, .75, 1, -0.6, -0.45, -0.6, 1), 3, 3),
                                 sample.method = "LHS", max.iter = 100) #, seed = i

  mvfyfueu <- rbind2(mvfyfueu, mat.fyfueu)
}
```

But at the end of the parallel run I get an empty mvfyfueu matrix:

```
> mvfyfueu
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
```

Which is quite different result than in the serial run. What should I correct? Thanks

Comment: Try using an implicit return after the last line of your current `for_each` body, i.e. `mvfyfueu` would be your new last line in the body; and also assign the `for_each` call to an object named `mvfyfueu` - `mvfyfueu <- for_each(...) %dopar% {...}`. I think this should fix the issue.

Comment: This makes `mvfyfueu` a list where in each iteration new columns are added to the list. What I would like is to have a matrix where in each iteration new rows are created. But it improved the results. thanks!

Comment: You have a TON of static variables in there!  Try giving them unique names, or combining them into a vector, and feeding that vector to your function. That will be much faster than redefining them every time thru the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have an appropriate set of objects to test your functions, or the time to create a comparable version of your script, I'm going to just use some toy data and a trivial process to demonstrate -

```
library(iterators)
library(foreach)
## your parallel backend setup may 
## be different, but that shouldn't
## affect anything
library(doSNOW)
library(parallel)
##
mvfyfueu <- matrix( , nrow = 0, ncol = 3)
iters <- 100
v1 <- v2 <- v3 <- 1:100
##
cl <- parallel::makeCluster("SOCK",3)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
##
mvfyfueu <- foreach(
  icount(iters),
  .combine=rbind) %dopar% {

    mat_row <- matrix(
      c(sample(v1),
        sample(v2),
        sample(v3)),
      nrow=1,
      ncol=3,
      byrow=TRUE)
    mat_row
  }
##
stopCluster(cl)
##
> dim(mvfyfueu)
[1] 100   3
> head(mvfyfueu)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   80   95   77
[2,]   75   24   57
[3,]   33   89   67
[4,]   29   91   75
[5,]   18   75   20
[6,]   54   44   25
```

When you use `foreach` you should most definitely take advantage of the `.combine` argument, which determines how your data is combined (in my experience, this is usually `rbind`). When you do this you don't need to explicitly `rbind` objects from each iteration with a global object in your `foreach` body, the `.combine` argument takes care of this. And as I noted in my comment, I believe it is necessary to assign the `foreach` call to an object. Let me know if this helps, and if not, feel free to post some sample data for testing your code.